# Oracle - drop synonym IF EXISTS

Tags: oracle11g

Using MSSQL - I can drop synonym only if it exist:
[DROP SYNONYM (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174996.aspx)

But in Oracle (11g) drop synonym causes my script to error if it doesn't exit, is there a way to mimic the MSSQL it exist?

Comment: Did the solution I provided stopped working for you? The answer you now accepted is more or less a copy of mine.

Comment: my bad, reverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a PLSQL anonymous block:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'drop synonym YOUR_SYNONYM';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode != -1434 then
         raise;
      end if;
end;
/
```

It will drop your synonym if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will just suppress the error. It will raise any error other than "synonym does not exist" to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can write: **CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM**

Comment: You can. But that does not *drop* a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pragma to define an exception which you can then handle.
Assuming you are doing something in a loop...

```
    declare
      NOSYN  exception;
      pragma exception_init ( NOSYN, -1434 );

    /* 1434 is the Oracle error for synonym does not exist */

    begin

    /*
     * Loop here where you synonym name gets assigned to the variable mysyn
     */


        begin
          execute immediate 'drop synonym '||mysyn;
        exception
          when NOSYN then
           dbms_output.put_line( 'Synonym does not exist... skipping' );
        end;

      end loop;
    end;
    /
```